# Salvar valor variável javascript no banco de dados

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

```
function showpos(position){
  lat=position.coords.latitude
  lon=position.coords.longitude
var enderDe = (+lat+',' +lon);
```

Como faço pra salvar a variável `enderDe` no meu banco de dados?!

Comment: Qual é a linguagem usada no servidor?

Comment: Se a linguagem utilizada for PHP, utilize ajax

Comment: php,... porém queria salvar sem o usuário precisar apertar algum botão,.. aii por post não daria certo

Comment: Ajax não tem nada haver com ação do usuário clicar em botão amigo.

Comment: desculpe cara, mas se estou perguntando aqui, já se supõe que não entendo sobre,...

Comment: Você utiliza `jQuery`? Se sim, dá pra fazer uma resolução bem fácil. Se não, pode adaptar para o Vanilla.

Comment: não utilizo, até então só php e html, agora chegou no momento que preciso aprender,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com as tuas respostas, usando [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), podes tentar o seguinte:

```
function showpos(position) {
  lat=position.coords.latitude;
  lon=position.coords.longitude;
  var latlon = JSON.stringify({lat:lat,lon:lon});
  saveLatLon(latlon);
}

function saveLatLon(pos) {
  $.post('url/do/teu/php.php',pos,function(data) {
    console.log(data); // aqui voce trata data como quiser
  }
}
```

no lado do php terás que fazer qualquer coisa como

```
if (isset($_POST['lat']) && isset($_POST['lon'])) {
    // chamada ao MySQL e tratamento de dados aqui
}
```

Para não usar jQuery, precisas de usar o [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) para fazer uma chamada AJAX ao teu PHP.